# CAPICOM dll not working in x64 bit server

Tags: security, cryptography

I am using CAPICOM dll in my project for certificate generation. On my local machine that is 32 bit sysatem it is working fine but on server where I host my application that is 64 bit server machine it gives 0x80090020 error.

As my local machine I register CAPICOM.dll with regsvr32 CAPICOM.dll command in system32 folder and also register the CAPICOM.dll with regsvr32 CAPICOM.dll command in system32 and syswow64 both folders. Message appears that dll registered successfully.

When I run my application then it will gives the 0x80090020 error. this error means is "Internal Server Error".

I don't want to use the other alternatives of CAPICOM.dll.

Comment: CAPICOM is obsolete for a long time. No wonder it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 64-bit version of "CAPICOM.dll" placed in system32 folder on 64-bit machine. I'm not sure about regsvr32 command for them. It can be different for 64-bit libraries.